# How to crop an image in a desired shape

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm trying to develop an easy game. But then, I came across this problem with my `UIImage`.
When I import an image, I get this annoying background on this ball, not just the ball itself. So when I play with this ball, this background has to match the `UIView` color, or else it will look weird. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: where is your image ?

Comment: My image is in the supporting file. Do you want me to upload the actual image here? It's just a simple black ball with a white background color.

Comment: why not using a black ball with transparent background? it's easier

Comment: you can use Quartz2d to achieve your effect, but I don't see the necessary. a photoshop preprocess would be much easier

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get a mask shape image with a mask:

```
//beCroppedImage is the image be cropped, maskImage is a image with a white background color and a black sharp that ever you want.
theShapeImage = [beCroppedImage maskImageWithMask:maskImage];



- (UIImage *)maskImageWithMask:(UIImage*)mask {
    CGImageRef imgRef = [self CGImage];
    CGImageRef maskRef = [mask CGImage];
    CGImageRef actualMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);
    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imgRef, actualMask);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
    CGImageRelease(masked);
    CGImageRelease(actualMask);
    return image;
}
```